# Devise: sign in with two possible encrypted passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, md5, bcrypt

My app works with the Devise gem for authentication, but I want customize it for sign in with two possible encrypted passwords, due to my previous app worked with MD5. I've two fields in my users table: **encrypted_password** and **encrypted_old_password** (I've created), I want check if exists the value **encrypted_password** and if the password sent matches the one set, otherwise, check if it does with MD5 and if true, then replace the value **encrypted_password**.

How I do this?

Comment: "how do I build the "recover_old_password" to update encrypted_password if not sign in and then the user can access?"

Comment: @markotom Did not get the question

Comment: I edited my question, better?

Comment: You could generate a random password for all the users and let only the `encrypted_password` field. And then, notify thro email notification or even with a clear and good text explanation what is going on, and ask them to create a new one. Just an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if my answer is fancy, but works for me. I hope someone can improve what I did.

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  def create
    recover_old_password unless user_signed_in?

    resource = warden.authenticate! auth_options
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in resource_name, resource

    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  def recover_old_password

    email = params[:user]['email']
    pass  = Digest::MD5.hexdigest params[:user]['password']

    @user = User.find_by_email_and_encrypted_old_password(email, pass)

    if @user.blank?

      resource = warden.authenticate! auth_options
      respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

    elsif

      if !@user.encrypted_password.nil?
        @user.encrypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create params[:user]['password']
        @user.save
        create
      end  

    end

  end

end
```